# Me podrían ayudar con este programa?, es un arreglo bidemensional, lo que quiero hacer es una tabla para poder organizar los datos

Tags: c++, array

El enunciado es:

> Se le solicita a usted que elabore un programa en C que permita lo
>   siguiente:
>
> A)  Los datos que se pidan muéstralos en una tabla, usar una sola
>   pantalla. Usar gotoxy.
>
> B)  Entre menos líneas de código mejor,
>   indentar el programa, comentar el programa con
>       los nombres de los integrantes del equipo.
>
> a)  Registrar la información de las ventas por mes de cada una de las
>   Agencias.
>       Preguntar de cuál Agencia se quieren llenar datos.  b)  Mostrar en pantalla el resumen de ventas de cada agencia. 
>       Preguntar de cuál Agencia se quieren mostrar datos. c)  Mostrar las ventas del año de una Agencia
>       Preguntar de cuál Agencia se quieren mostrar las ventas. d)  Mostar el promedio de ventas en el mes de diciembre, incluye a todas
>   las Agencias. e)  Mostrar el número de la Agencia que tuvo mayores
>   ventas en el mes de mayo. f)  Indicar en qué mes se registraron las
>   menores ventas del año, considerando todas las Agencias.

Esto es lo que he realizado hasta ahora:
En mi código los meses se colocan en orden ascendente y tienen que ir en una tabla, como la de la imagen, tampoco se como ingresar los datos adentro de la tabla

```
using namespace std;

void calendario(int agencia); 
string nombreMes(int mes);

int main() { 
    int agencia; 
    cout << "Colocar agencia: "; 
    cin >> agencia;      

    calendario(agencia); 
    system("pause"); 
}

void calendario(int agencia) { 
    for (int mes= 1; mes <= 12; mes++) {  
        cout <<"Mes: " << nombreMes(mes) << "\n"; cout << "Agen1 Agen2 Agen3 Agen4 Agen5\n"; cout << "\n"; 
    } 
}

string nombreMes(int mes) { 
    switch(mes) { 
        case 1: return "Enero"; 
        case 2: return "Febrero"; 
        case 3: return "Marzo"; 
        case 4: return "Abril"; 
        case 5: return "Mayo"; 
        case 6: return "Junio"; 
        case 7: return "Julio"; 
        case 8: return "Agosto"; 
        case 9: return "Septiembre"; 
        case 10: return "Octubre"; 
        case 11: return "Noviembre"; 
        default: return "Diciembre"; 
   } 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una pregunta debe incluir siempre un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Poner solo el enunciado da a entender que buscas que otros escriban el código por ti.

Comment: Y cuál es la pregunta? Tienes el enunciado, tienes tu código... cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: ya lo espcifiqué para que se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: Vale, gracias por editar la pregunta y detallar el resultado buscado (eso está bien). Lo que sigue faltando es que nos expliques por qué el código no resuelve el problema. :) Errores, comportamientos inesperados

Comment: ya amigo,¿así se entiende mejor?